# std::string type lost in tuple

Tags: string, templates, c++11, tuples

Can someone explain what's going on here?  Output from GCC 5.2:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <string>
#include <typeinfo>

template <typename... Args>
void foo (Args&&... args) {
    std::tuple<Args...> t = std::tie(args...);
    std::cout << std::is_same<int, std::tuple_element_t<0, decltype(t)>>::value << '\n';  // true
    std::cout << std::is_same<std::string, std::tuple_element_t<1, decltype(t)>>::value << '\n';  // false
    std::cout << typeid(std::tuple_element_t<1, decltype(t)>).name() << '\n';  // A3_C (what's this???)
}

int main() {
    foo (5, "hi");
}
```

Why is the std::string type lost, and what has it turn into instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`"string"` - is a `const char[N]` array, **not** `std::string`. In this case `const char[] = {'h', 'i', '\0'} -> const char[3] ->` **Array** of **3** elements of type `char` (A3_C).
Use `std::string("hi")` to make string or enable user literals and write `"hi"s`

Answer (score 1):

`"hi"` (string literal) is of the type `const char[3]`, not `std::string`